# What AWS CLI tools are installed by default on EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using an Amazon Linux EC2 instance and am wondering What AWS CLI tools are installed by default on it.

Is it just the EC2 CLI API tools? How can one tell? Also where is the preferred single location on an EC2 instance to install each of the various CLI tools (RDS, cloudwatch, etc.) if they aren't installed already?

If you might answer each of these questions I'd be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03, here's the [list of installed packages](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.03-packages/).

To answer your question, here's the list of AWS tools:

- aws-amitools-ec2-1.4.0.7
- aws-apitools-as-1.0.61.0
- aws-apitools-cfn-1.0.9
- aws-apitools-common-1.1.0
- aws-apitools-ec2-1.5.5.0
- aws-apitools-elb-1.0.17.0
- aws-apitools-iam-1.5.0
- aws-apitools-mon-1.0.12.1
- aws-apitools-rds-1.8.002
- aws-cfn-bootstrap-1.1
- aws-scripts-ses-2012.05.15

[According to Amazon Linux AMI Basics:](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonLinuxAMIBasics.html)

> to allow the installation of multiple versions of the API and AMI
>   tools, we have placed symlinks to the desired versions of these tools
>   in **/opt/aws**, as described here:
>
> **/opt/aws/bin**—Symlink farm to /bin directories in each of the installed
>   tools directories.
>
> **/opt/aws/{apitools|amitools}**—Products are installed in directories of
>   the form [name]-version and symlink [name] attached to the most
>   recently installed version.
>
> **/opt/aws/{apitools|amitools}/[name]/environment.sh**—Used by
>   /etc/profile.d/aws-apitools-common.sh to set product-specific
>   environment variables (EC2_HOME, etc.).

Comment: hmm, i'm not seeing an an /opt/aws directory, perhaps /opt/aws is just the suggested directory?

Comment: I just brought up a new instance using Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03, and the /opt/aws does exist.  What AMI are you using?

Comment: sorry about that, you are right, they are in /opt/aws, i think i was looking at one of my previous EC2 instances which was Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

There are no fixed standards or set rules about what is installed on AMIs in general.

Different Linux distros and different AMI publishers each decide what they want to put in their image and where.

In fact, an AMI doesn't even need to give you command line access to your instance through ssh if they don't want to.

If you have a specific AMI series in mind (Amazon Linux, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS from Canonical, CentOS 5.5 from RightScale) then update your question to include this.

Comment: -@eric thanks, i'm using an Amazon Linux AMI though I could switch to Ubuntu if that if generally more accepted? Tthough I figure the Amazon linux might have the AWS tools installed?

Comment: I think the choice between Amazon Linux and Ubuntu is pretty much up to your distro preference.  I happen to be an Ubuntu user and recently posted a couple blog posts about how to install the AWS tools with Ubuntu packages http://alestic.com/2012/05/aws-command-line-packages and through Amazon software downloads http://alestic.com/2012/09/aws-command-line-tools

Comment: thanks, so no toolsets are installed by default? I guess I'm not seeing the difference between toolsets that come as ubuntu packages and those that aren't. `sudo apt-get install ec2-api-tools` seems easy enough to me on Linux AMI or Ubuntu, yes/no?

Comment: @timpeterson: EC2 API tools is just one of many AWS tool sets available.  The Ubuntu package will not always be completely up to date with the downloadable software from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

For the record: the "minimal" variant of Amazon Linux does not have the full suite of CLI tools. Doing a `yum install ec2-tools` didn't get me what I wanted, so I just created a new instance with the non-minimal AMI. I also found that this minimal Linux isn't any more space-efficient, at least as originally configured; the additional 6 GB that would go to the root partition is left unallocated.